# how to change field hint in ui component of react to amplify passing him a funtional component

Tags: reactjs, hint, aws-amplify

how to change field hint in ui component of react to amplify passing him a funtional component

i am trying with this

```
 <AmplifySignIn
          slot="sign-in"
          usernameAlias="email"
          headerText="Iniciar sesión"
          submitButtonText="Iniciar sesión"
          formFields={[
            {
              type: "email",
              label: "Email",
              placeholder: "usuario@email.com",
              required: true,
            },
            {
              type: "password",
              label: "Contraseña",
              placeholder: "contraseña",
              required: true,
              hint: <LabelResetPass />,
            },
          ]}
        ></AmplifySignIn>
```

but for the hint field it doesn't recognize it